# Java reads file directory and creates a link to a pdf

Tags: java

What I'm trying to accomplish is to read a file directory and print a link to the pdf, but the kicker is that some of the PDFs end with 123456_2018-01.pdf, 456234_2018-01a.pdf, or 123456_2018-01 with some letter following it. I can't figure out what expression am I supposed to use that will capture all the pdfs for that month.

```
    for (File obj : contentsOfDirectory) {
                if (obj.isFile()) {
                    if (!obj.getName().substring(0, 2).equals("._")) {

                        String file = "this is the file directory";
                        String pdfBills = file + obj.getName().toString();

                        String year = pdfBills.substring(pdfBills.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);

                        if (obj.getName().toString().endsWith("01.pdf")) {
            %>
                        <li><a href=<%=pdfBills%>>January <%=year%></a><br> <%
                        } else if (obj.getName().toString().endsWith("02.pdf")) {
            %>
                        <li><a href=<%=pdfBills%>>February <%=year%></a><br> <%
```

I've tried using `.matches(^01*.pdf)` , but it never shows the link on the page which makes me believe I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: FYI `obj.getName().substring(0, 2)` will throw if directory contains a filename one-character long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) kind of problem to me so use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. By positively matching what we want, it implicitly ignores files that don't conform (like your `._` example)

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*_(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})\\.pdf$");

for (File obj : contentsOfDirectory) {
  if (obj.isFile()) 
    String file = "this is the file directory";
    String pdfBills = file + obj.getName().toString();

    Matcher m = p.matcher(pdfBills);
    if (m.matches()) {
      int year = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
      int month = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
      // ... do stuff with year and month
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain the Pattern.compile part. Its doing what I'm wanting and I want to add this bit of code into other projects of mine and I would like to know a little more how its determining this.

Comment: Added some links into the answer. `Pattern.compile` creates a Regular Expression which can be used multiple times to `match` input strings like `pdfBills`. The regex I used has two "(capturing) (groups)" so, when it matches, `m.group(1)` contains the year etc

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of looking at the end of the filename, you inspected the beginning? It looks like the first part of the filename is consistently YYYY-MM, you could then parse out the year and the month using `.substring()` like so:

```
String year = pdfBills.substring(0, 4);
String month = pdfBills.substring(5, 7);
```

Then, you can convert your month numeric String to a human readable month String like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
int intMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
String monthName = symbols.getMonths()[intMonth-1];
```

Comment: That could work, but I failed to mention that the whole file name would be like 112323-001_2018-01 and that's my fault for not stating it. Anything before '*_2018-01.pdf' is completely irrelevant. I'm only focused on the information after '*_*'.